# Property power-supply for an external pwm-backlight IC

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I have this LCD panel:

[image]

LED panel's backlight is driven by the MIC2297 chip which takes two signals:

- `BRT` - PWM signal for setting brightness of the LCD's background LEDs.
- `BL_EN` that - gpio signal that enables or disables the LCD's background LEDs.

MIC2297 is powered from the +12V.

---

Now I connected this display to the Beaglebone Black's (BBB's) expansion connector and I am already running Linux on the BBB's microcontroller AM335x.

In order to enable the backlight I have to properly define it in the device tree i.e. `.dts` file. Currently I managed to set this up:

```
backlightt: backlight {
    compatible = "pwm-backlight";
    pwms = <&ehrpwm1 0 500000000>;
    power-supply <>; // ???
    enable-gpios = <&gpio2 3 0>;
    brightness-levels = <0 4 8 16 32 64 128 255>;
    default-brightness-level = <7>;
};
```

What I don't understand is the property `power-supply`. How can I know which regulator to use? My devicce uses external 12V! This is really confusing! Why do we even have to specify the regulator?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...

PWM backlight requires a property "power-supply" that points to some regulator inside the AM335x. This regulator is used to set the output voltage of the PWM - so we don't need to put any kind of voltage regulator between an AM335x and the backlight IC *(which might only support 1.5V PWM input on some mobile devices)*. This is actually really useful.